# 'Wird/verb' + 'so' sentences

Tags: translation, sentence-structure, german-to-english

I have a question about the below type of sentence, composed of a first position (auxiliary) verb + a second/third clause beginning 'so'. Here is a specimen 'problem' sentence here for me, with my working EN version:

> Wird der Körper Christi am Kreuz aufgespannt und zu einer Figur des Kreises gemacht, der von den angenagelten Armen und Füßen geformt wird, so wird Elisabeth mit dem Penis Blaubarts in die Mitte ihres Körpers “getroffen …

becomes

> As the body of Christ is stretched on the cross and made into a circular figure formed by nailed arms and feet, so Elisabeth is ‘afflicted’ by the penis of Bluebeard in the middle of her body.

Am I correct in making a parallelism between the clauses here of the kind '(just) as . . . so' in English?

Comment: The statement of the sentence makes no sense.

Comment: I'd say _yes_, but that makes not a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should lose the "so" after the comma in your English translation. The German sentence could also be written as "In der gleichen Weise, in welcher der Körper ... gemacht wird, wird Elisabeth ..." or "Wenn der Körper .. wird, dann wird Elisabeth ..."

Answer (score 2):

This is the language of literary studies, which sometimes likes using ambiguous structures and structures that are hard to interpret.

In German, dependent V1 clauses mostly have a conditional meaning.

> **Erfolgt** kein Widerspruch, (so) kann der Gläubiger den Erlaß des Vollstreckungsbefehls beantragen.
>   **Wenn** kein Widerspruch **erfolgt**, (so) kann …
>   **If** no appeal is made …

The meaning can also be adversative, i.e. expressing a contrast.

> **Wird** im Schadenersatz lediglich die Verantwortung für die Haftung festgelegt, (so) geht es im Strafrecht um die Schuldfrage.
>   **Während** im Schadenersatz lediglich die Verantwortung für die Haftung festgelegt **wird**, (so) geht es …
>   **While** tort law merely defines liabilities …

The adversative meaning would fit your example.

> While the body of Christ is stretched on the cross, Elisabeth is …

However, a conditional interpretation is possible as well, if the condition is interpreted not as the crucifixion of Christ, but as conceiving of the crucifixion in a certain way (i.e. as making the body of Christ into the figure of the circle).

> If the body of Christ **is conceived of as** being stretched on the cross, Elizabeth **can be conceived of as** being …

The translation using a comparison with *as* works in so far as it expresses the same idea less explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. David - that's brilliantly on the ball, technically speaking, and also addresses a possible ambiguity (the 'adversative' vs the 'conditional' interpretation) I may need to take up with the author.